# Getting Started with Sencha Eclipse Plugin

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I created a sencha touch project using sencha cmd and imported the project into my eclipse IDE. But the script explorer is showing so many information compared to what i see on their blog. i am follwoing the same instruction as they mention in it. what am i missing..Below is screen shot of my project in eclipse.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove and again add project to eclipse.